# Using with C#, How to fetch last recyle time of application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

In the IIs, regular interval time configured as 1740.

In the production, event logs are not getting due to `GenerateRecyleEventLogEntry` is false. So we are unable to get logs.  With help c# ,  we need to figure out the next recycle time.

Advance Thanks!

Comment: Impossible it is. The event log is the only feasible option.

Comment: _"we need to figure out the next recycle time"_ -  why exactly?

Comment: Are you asking how to find out the next time the app will recycle or are you asking how to use the XML configuration file behind IIS (C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config if muscle memory serves) to see if the value has been set or?

Comment: Here are the steps to calculate the next recycle time in C# given a regular interval of ==>      
reminer = currenttime.min % interval (1740) ;
minu = interval - reminder;
datetim.now.addminute(minu ) this is  recycle datetime;

Comment: You can't know the last recycle time, how to figure out the next recycle time? It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to combine a bit of code from Microsoft.Web.Administration with a bit of System code for managing processes, and handle what to do when there are multiple worker processes (either there are multiple workers due to the configuration, or if you happen to check during a recycle).  This can be extended to work with a remote IIS server if desired.  I've hardcoded 1740 (29 hours) for this as an example, but if I were to actually use this code I would replace that with the actual recycle configuration on the apppool.

To handle multiple worker processes I've taken the oldest worker process start time as the one that matters.

Add a reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration, and the code can look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace IISLongestRunningWorkerProcess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appPoolName = "YourAppPoolName"; // Replace with the actual app pool name

            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];
                if (appPool != null)
                {
                    WorkerProcess longestRunningProcess = null;
                    TimeSpan longestRunningTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    DateTime earliestStartTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                    foreach (WorkerProcess workerProcess in appPool.WorkerProcesses)
                    {
                        DateTime startTime = Process.GetProcessById(workerProcess.ProcessId).StartTime;
                        TimeSpan runningTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;

                        if (runningTime > longestRunningTime)
                        {
                            longestRunningTime = runningTime;
                            longestRunningProcess = workerProcess;
                            earliestStartTime = startTime;
                        }
                    }

                    if (longestRunningProcess != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Longest running process ID: {longestRunningProcess.ProcessId}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Running for: {longestRunningTime}");

                        DateTime nextRecycleTime = earliestStartTime.AddHours(29);
                        TimeSpan timeUntilNextRecycle = nextRecycleTime - DateTime.Now;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Time until next recycle: {timeUntilNextRecycle}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No worker processes found.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Application pool '{appPoolName}' not found.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , We don't have workerProcess.GetStartTime(); method.  please check here    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.workerprocess?view=iis-dotnet

Comment: I've corrected that now.  I also played loosely with DateTime and TimeSpan in the first version which also caused errors.  This code now compiles, and runs (and works!) for me on VS 2019 / .NET 4.7.2.